# Erro na compilação do meu arquivo .tex

Tags: string, textview

O erro dá-me a indicação de algum problema no arquivo `subcaption.sty`, resultando no seguinte erro:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.64 \caption@AtBeginDocument
>   {%
>   The control sequence at the end of the top line

Comment: É LaTeX? Se sim, parece que suas tags estão erradas. Ao [edit] a pergunta, adicione também o seu código que está gerando o erro.

Comment: verifica se o `\usepackage{subcaption}` está antes do `\begin{document}`